# Número máximo de linhas recomendado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe alguma **PEP** ou sugestão de boa prática que define qual seria a quantidade máxima recomendada de linhas que um módulo deve ter?
No meu caso por exemplo, eu mantenho mais de uma classe por módulo, obviamente classes que estejam dentro do mesmo contexto, classes *domains* por exemplo. Porém, tenho um módulo que já está ultrapassando 450 linhas, e não sei se já seria hora de separar.
Em outras linguagens como Java e C# geralmente se mantém uma única classe por arquivo, mas em Python é comum ter mais de uma, onde os arquivos são chamados de módulos.

Comment: Priorize a semântica. Estilo é uma das últimas coisas. Em outras palavras: se faz sentido manter tudo no mesmo arquivo, mesmo passando de 1000 linhas, deixe assim. Separar adiciona complexidade e isso só é bom quando resolve algum problema.

Comment: Como o @AndersonCarlosWoss , acredito também que o mais importate seja o contexto em que cada função está inserida, se faz sentido elas estarem juntas mesmo criando um arquivo grande(classe/módulo) seria o correto. Mas analisar se é possível quebrar em subclasses ou em outros módulos é importante para manter a reusabilidade e legibilidade do seu código. PEP-8 fala sobre tamanho de limite da linha mas nunca vi nada sobre limite de linhas em módulo ou classe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) é o guia de boas práticas mais seguido e bem aceito dentro do python, nele você encontra diversas 'convenções' para a escrita de seu código.
Dividir seu módulo em outros módulos menores também pode variar de acordo com a **finalidade** para qual você está programando. Se é uma aplicação desktop talvez seja mais vantajoso ter blocos mais robustos, por outra via, aplicações web tendem a ter o código mais bem dividido.
Cito aqui uma passagem do livro [Thoo scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11), que reúne convenções e dicas úteis para a organização de seu projeto:

> Quando estiver em dúvida, mantenha os apps pequenos.

Embora o livro seja voltado para o desenvolvimento web, pessoalmente, procuro sempre manter essa perspectiva em mente, porém vale a pena levar em consideração o fator semântico do código, como dito previamente pelo Anderson. 
Se faz sentido que todo aquele seu bloco de código esteja junto em um só lugar, e você julgue que quebra-lo em fragmentos menores apenas dificultaria a leitura do mesmo, não há porque fase-lo. 

O PEP8 está ai para te auxiliar, mas sua dúvida, como você pode observar, parece ser um tanto que subjectiva. Deixo algumas recomendações de leitura que espero que te ajude. Se você é um programador solo procure ler o PEP e achar o que lhe serve melhor, se programa com uma equipe, procure conversar com os outros programadores e achar uma forma que seja inteligível para todos.

**Leitura Complementar**

- [Guia de Estilo](https://wiki.python.org.br/GuiaDeEstilo)
- [Code Style (The hitchhiker's guide to python)](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/)